# Recommended JScrollPane navigation widget

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Can anyone recommend a decent Swing widget for navigating JScrollPanes?  I refer to the type of navigation window you often see in CAD applications that allow you to reposition the viewport by dragging the position of small box (the view port) within a larger box (the underlying component).

To date I've found [this](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t21355.html), but wondered if there was anything else out there, perhaps as part of a UI library?

Ideally I would also like to render a scaled version of the component in the navigation window.

**EDIT**

To address some of mKorbel's questions:

- The application I'm developing is Swing-based.
- The component within the JScrollPane is a JPanel for which I've overridden the paintComponent method in order to draw shapes using Java 2D.
- Hence I'm effectively mixing Java 2D and Swing.

Comment: questions 1) CAD applications is based on AWT or Swing, 2) whats type of, 3) is possible to mixing CAD Component with Swing container, 4) nice linked code example +1 5) there must exist something for diplaying world maps, f.e. Google ???

Comment: swinglabs incubator has a JXScrollMap, it's somewhere in Karl Schaefer's section (he's restructuring, not entirely sure where currently ;-) http://java.net/projects/jdnc-incubator

Comment: @kleopatra:  Thanks, I'll check it out (when I find the code).  I've used Swinglabs in the past (~2005) but it seemed to reach a point where it was no longer under development and some components were buggy.  Has it progressed recently?

Comment: biased me would say sure it progressed during the last 7 years :-) And bugs are everywhere, reports or better patches welcome!

Comment: @kleopatra: OK cool; I'll definitely take a look then.  If you add as an answer I will accept.  BTW Have these fixed that bug in JXErrorDialog yet?  Last time I used it to show an Exception, it threw an Exception (the irony!).

Comment: I see the irony ;-) If you or anybody reported an issue you might check in swingx' jira to see if it's fixed (me not overly familiar with the component)

Comment: JXErrorPane.showDialog works well for me in SwingX. (JXErrorDialog is a private class, maybe it was public in the old days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swinglabs incubator](http://java.net/projects/jdnc-incubator) has a JXScrollMap, a candidate for future addition. It's [in Karl Schaefer's section under scrollmap](http://java.net/projects/jdnc-incubator/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/kschaefe?rev=3378) (he's restructuring, so not entirely sure how stable that latter link is).